# Current Amplitude Distribution Lossless Transmission Line

Tags: current, transmission, line, amplitude

I need to proof that the formula for Current Amplitude Distribution in a Lossless Transmission Line it's the following and I don't know where to start from... A little help would be appreciated. Thanks! [image]

Comment: You don't know where to start from and anyone reading you profile doesn't know what your skill level and knowledge base is. Do you see the problem?

Comment: @Andyaka my skills are very low, but I've found this: http://home.sandiego.edu/~ekim/e171f00/lectures/tl.pdf look on slide 15. In my formula I don't understand from where the pi and phi at the end of the formula came from...